# Как в WPF связать свойство IsEnabled кнопки с выделенностью элемента ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

В проекте `WPF` имеется `ListView` (или `ListBox` и т.д.), с набором итемов, подключенных через `ItemsSource` при запуске приложения. Изначально не выбран ни один элемент. Рядом имеется кнопка, изначально недоступная, но которая должна стать доступной, когда элемент списка будет выбран и обратно сделаться недоступной, если для списка например будет вызвано `SelectedItem` = `null`. Как в `XAML`-разметке через `Binding` связать доступность кнопки с выделенностью элемента? Т.е. как сделать что-то наподобие `IsEnabled={Binding ElementName=listView1, Path=SelectedItem!=null}`?

Comment: думаю удобней будет кнопке назначить команду и уже доступностью выполнения команды рулить. что то так:
 private DelegateCommand _removeValueCommand;
        public DelegateCommand RemoveValueCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _removeValueCommand ?? (_removeValueCommand = new DelegateCommand(DoRemoveValueCommand, CanDoRemoveValueCommand));
            }
        }

и в сеттере SelectedItem вызывать _removeValueCommand?.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

Comment: @Сергей надо было это оформить как ответ, а не комментарий

Answer (score 2):

Такой вариант: изначально кнопка доступная, меняет свое состояние если Selected (поле в коде) null

```
<Button Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Selected}">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="CommandParameter" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нам понадобится класс-конвертер

```
public class NullToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null ? false : true;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

С учетом того, что этот класс лежит в корне проекта

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:NullToBooleanConverter x:Key="Converter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Тогда для кнопки

```
<Button x:Name="button"
        IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedItem,
        Converter={StaticResource Converter}, ElementName=listView}"/>
```